# In codeigniter 4, I have issued a POST request using jQuery, but the request does not reach the server

Tags: jquery, post, get, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I am porting my code from CI3 to CI4. An AJAX POST request using jQuery that has been working in CI3 is not reaching the server code.

---

Here is the client side code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'recordCreate/' + serialCode,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data: data},
    dataType : 'text',
}).done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

My routes

```
$routes->post('recordCreate/(:alpha)', 'AjaxWrite::recordCreate/$1');
```

and the controller is this

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
class AjaxWrite extends Controller{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }
  function recordCreate($serailCode)
  {
    echo urldecode($serailCode);
    echo $this->request->getPost('data');
  }
}
```

and is contained in a file named 'AjaxWrite.php'

With this, I get the error

> Controller or its method is not found:
>   App\Controllers\RecordCreate::qweq

where 'qweq' is the value of the serialCode I pass in the URL.

Comment: P;ease upload your code so others might help you.

Comment: Check your routes. It might be you need to define a $routes->post() for your AJAX URL.

Comment: Thank you @timbrownlaw for this information. I was using $routes->get() for all my routes. It must be something to do with routes. Now with $routes->post(), I get the error `Controller or its method is not found: App\Controllers\ControllerMethod::parameter`

Comment: Can you add your routes into your question. What you have described doesn't look right.

Comment: I have added the routes and also the jQuery (client) and the controller. Have a look.

Comment: I had a good ole play with this and I would say that your expected (:alpha) is something else. Have you tried using (:any)? Or actually checking what your data is? Is is a string or something else?

Comment: Thank you so much @timbrownlaw. Why I was still getting an error after changing routes from  `$routes->get()` to `$routes->post()`, I honestly can't tell. What you told me was the correct thing - **need to define a $routes->post() for your AJAX URL**. So the code is working correctly as it appears on the question now. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am very glad you got it working :)

Comment: Then what do I do about the question? It is answered and I would not like it to hang around as if it is not answered. I would not like to delete it either because it may help another newbie like me crossing from CI3 to CI4.

Comment: @owino consider in self answering, with a reference to Tim's help... check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 4):

CodeIgniter 4 is a rewrite of the framework and is not backwards compatible. From my experience so far, porting an app from version 3 to 4 looks like one is also rewriting the app.

The documentation says... [It is more appropriate to think of converting your app, rather than upgrading it](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/installation/upgrade_4xx.html).

In version 3, routing was same no matter how the client code made a request. In version 4, your route should reflect your intention at the client.

My first AJAX requests with CI4 were GETs. When I used POST request for the first time, I tunnelled the request to the controller through
`$routes->get()`
and is the reason the request did not reach the controller. From the comments section you will see @timbrownlaw (probably very experienced with CI) smelled this as the problem.

So the solution here is that the jQuery (client) POST request should pass through a

`$routes->post()`

route as it appears in the code in the question. Before @timbrownlaw helped, the route had been

`$routes->get()`.

You can see [more from the documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#using-http-verbs-in-routes).